# Umbraco Render grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

Hi I am having a lot of trouble with rendering an umbraco grid.

I have a solution with umbraco 7.6 and MVC.
So in my controller I want to try and add the rendered grid to my model, so I can call that model in the view.

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult BlogItem()
{
    var model = new BlogItemViewModel();
    // GET grid 1
    var aboutGrid = CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("gridLayout");
    //add to model.
    model.GridLayout = new HtmlString(aboutGrid.ToHtmlString());
    return View(model);
}
```

And in my view I should be able to just call this:

```
@Model.GridLayout
```

But I get an exception, which doesn't really tell me much in my controller when trying to call it.

> System.Web.HttpCompileException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
>
> $exception error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UmbracoViewPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"}   System.Web.HttpCompileException

**Edit 1**

```
@model Carinas_Univers.Models.BlogItemViewModel
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
```

i have a view model, master page, and a master controller.
the mastercontroller inherits from RenderMvcController

Answer (score 1):

Does your view inherit from `UmbracoViewPage`? If so then it sounds like it doesn't know what namespace `UmbracoViewPage` is in. The simple solution would be to change it to `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage`.

Answer (score 0):

You should load your custom class along with the Umbraco view page.

Have you tried this?

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Carinas_Univers.Models.BlogItemViewModel>
```

You need to get and load the current page within your controller in order to get the page properties and assign them to the model properties

To do that you can do the following:

```
var currentPageId =  UmbracoContext.Current.PageId;   
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
IPublishedContent content = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(currentPageId);
```

Comment: i get a "the type or name space could not be found", when adding that to my view. But it seems wierd that it should be nessesary. I should be able to add a grid to my viewmodel, and just display it.

Comment: @andrelange91 Have you build the project?

Comment: Where did you put the Model class? what is the path in the solution explorer?

Comment: solutionname.Models.ModelName    and yes i build the project.

Comment: i get a system.web http Compile exception, in my controller when i try to run it. "an external component has thrown an exception" on "aboutgrid"

Comment: I have edit the answer, look at the path of the model

Comment: the path does not make much sense to me.. and it does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to get the current page within your controller, i have edit my answer

Comment: but simply calling CurrentPage within my controller does this already ?